# jquery iframe css firefox bug?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, iframe

Without going in to detail on what these methods do, can anyone tell me why I get these weird results?

```
getCurrentIframe().findInIframe("h2").css("paddingLeft") // gives me "20px"
```

how ever if I do .get(0) or [0] to get the dom-element and then rewrap it in a $ I get:

```
$( getCurrentIframe().findInIframe("h2")[0]).css("paddingLeft") //it gives me "0px"
```

When I do an `.each`, `$(this).css("paddingLeft")` (within the each loop) also gives me 0px.

Im also getting different results on paddingLeft when I use this(from the parent window):
`iframe.contentWindow.$(selector).css("paddingLeft")  //gives me 20px`
but
`iframe.contents().find(selector).css("paddingLeft") //gives me 0px`

It seems that firefox is uncapable to find the correct css in iframes on an element unless it has the styles set inline. (like for example: if body has font-size:18 in css, but the elements css has font-size:40px, it will return 18px)

*boggled*

**added:**

```
  getCurrentIframe().findInIframe("h2").each(function() { console.log($(this).css("paddingLeft")) }).css("paddingLeft")
```

this prints out in firefox 0px  20px. How ever in chrome it prints out 20px 20px

Answer (score 0):

I've no answer for you, but I just ran into a very similar problem with the Galleryview plugin (http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview), which was failing when the following returned 'undefined':

```
j_panels.css('paddingLeft')
```

For once IE did the right thing, and FF failed! :-(  Anyway, your post here saved me some forehead banging:  adding 'padding: 0px" directly to the div in question took away the problem.

And, yes, this was in an iframe — a lightbox, in fact.  Interestingly, I never noticed anything with Colorbox, but we switched today to Fancybox and starting seeing an issue with Galleryview.

Comment: Yeah, ff does not seem to be able to calculate styles such as padding if the padding comes from a stylesheet. If the style is inline (like Frank said) it seems to work though. And I think I have banged my forehead enough for the both of us ;)

Answer (score 0):

Two things.  First, inline CSS styles are probably working better due to a timing issue with regards to the external CSS not being available when your script runs.

Second, iframe.contentWindow.$(selector) is weird I wouldn't expect it to get the same result.  I would bet that the .$() call is acting just like a call to $()-- by that I mean it would be selecting from all things on the page, not limited to the content window.

Comment: Yeah, inline styles work correctly. And I dont think the timing has anything to do with it, because when I run the commands through firebug I get the same results, styles from css-files are ignored.